# Running my function to convert a number to an 8 length binary number prints NameError: 'new_rule' is not defined although I've already defined it

Tags: python, function

```
rule = 90
def binary_conversion(new_rule):
    _bin = bin(rule)
    new_rule = _bin[2:]
    for char in (new_rule):
        if len(new_rule) < 8:
            new_rule = "0" + new_rule
        else:
            return(new_rule)

print(binary_conversion(new_rule))
```

Code returns --> NameError: name 'new_rule' is not defined.
It should show the 8 char length binary conversion.

Now if I run the code without the function it prints the correct conversion but instead prints it 6 times!

```
rule = 90
_bin = bin(rule)
new_rule = _bin[2:]
for char in new_rule:
    if len(new_rule) < 8:
        new_rule = "0" + new_rule
    else:
        print(new_rule)
```

Comment: `new_rule` is defined inside the function, thus it does not exist outside the function. Read about variable scope please.

Comment: print(binary_conversion(rule)) is probably what you meant

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to pass a variable *new_rule* to your function. That variable isn't in scope where you're trying to utilise it. Having said that, what I think you really meant was:

```
print(binary_conversion(rule))
```

You could also minimise your function to this:

```
def binary_conversion(new_rule):
    return f'{new_rule:08b}'
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first block of code, I believe you meant to use `print(binary_conversion(rule))`. `new_rule`is defined inside the function therefore its a local variable and can only be used inside the function.

For the second block of code, you are looping through new_rule while editing it:

```markdown
##Before looping:
new_rule = 1011010 # Which is a length of 7

##First loop:
len(new_rule) < 8 is True, so we add 0 at the beginning
new_rule = 01011010 # length of 8

##Second To 8th loop:
len(new_rule) < 8 is False because new_rule is 8 length long so we pring its value
```

Your mistake is you didn't pay attention to the length of new_rule whilst modifying its value.

Answer (score -1):

you can use zfill(8) to do it

```
bin(number)[2:].zfill(8)
```

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. You do not answer why there is a `NameError`.